# Un cas particulier de question - A particular kind of question

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

Bonjour,

J'aimerais que vous donniez votre avis concernant [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/false-friends-and-faux-amis-the-ultimate-collection). Elle a été fermée par une seule personne et je pense que c'est n'est pas un bon choix. Non seulement ce genre de question sont acceptées sur les autres sites de SE, mais en plus, c'est une excellente question, je veux dire par là que les réponses sont vraiment excellentes. Malgré la fermeture de la question, j'ai déjà appris en lisant les quelques réponses qui ont été écrites.

Par contre, je suis complètement contre le « résumé » qui a été fait : il semble que quelqu'un a fait de toutes les « réponses » une seule et grosse réponse. Ce n'est pas la bonne présentation pour ce genre de question.

Je voudrais aussi dire que certaines questions de ce type sont pour moi des références sur d'autres sites (que j'ai mis dans mes favoris et que je consulte de temps en temps pour voir si il y a des nouveautés dans le domaine, comme [celui-ci](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82/which-os-x-applications-do-you-find-indispensable) par exemple).

Le dernier argument est, comme je l'ai indiqué dans les commentaires, que ce genre de question va nécessairement attirer du monde sur le site via l'indexation que Google fait et que c'est un très bonne chose pour avoir une « masse critique » d'utilisateurs d'un site comme celui-ci.

Voilà, merci de donner votre avis sur le sujet.

---

Hello,

I would like your opinion on [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/false-friends-and-faux-amis-the-ultimate-collection). It has been closed by one person and I think it was not a good decision. Not only are these kind of questions accepted on other SE sites, but it's also an excellent question; what I mean by that is that the answers are really excellent. Despite the question being closed, I already learnt something by reading the few answers that have been written.

However, I'm totally against the "summary" which has been done: it seems that someone made a single unique response from all the answers. This is not the proper presentation for this kind of questions.

I would also like to say that some questions of that kind are for me references on other sites (which I added to my bookmarks and consult from time to time to see if there's anything new in that domain, such as [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82/which-os-x-applications-do-you-find-indispensable) for example).

My last point is, as I indicated in the comments, that this kind of questions will necessarily attract people to the site via the Google indexing and that it's a very good thing to reach a "critical mass" of users on a site such as this one.

Thanks for giving your opinion on the subject.

Comment: What makes you think that an aggregated answer is not a proper presentation? It is way easier to read this way than with several answers spread on several pages, *that* would be fastidious.

Comment: Because, as I said, this is a "reference" that you can check from time to time, to see new addition quickly, that's the best way. You don't have to read all the list again. You just sort the answers by date.

Comment: I have to disagree. SE sites are supposed to be reached mainly by passerby from search engines. “New additions” is irrelevant to them, but they could use a compact, usable list. If you really want to see recent changes, check the history.

Answer (score 6):

Les demandes de listes sont désormais rejetées sur la plupart des sites Stack Exchange. Voir [List questions: Community Wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki) et pas mal d'autres discussions sur les divers sites métas. Au début, elles étaient acceptées, puis on s'est aperçu que le format ne convient pas du tout : on se retrouve avec une grande quantité de réponses complètement déconnectées, triées n'importe comment, avec beaucoup de doublons. Donc, si tant est que cette question doit rester sur le site, c'est avec une unique réponse en wiki communautaire.

Pour l'instant, la question est close mais pas effacée. On peut donc continuer à éditer la réponse, mais pas ajouter de nouvelle réponse — ce qui est exactement ce qu'il faut si on cherche à établir une liste.

Je suis partisan d'effacer la question, parce que c'est de la mauvaise publicité pour le site. Pour qu'elle soit de la bonne publicité, il faudrait que nous produisions une liste de meilleure qualité que ce qui se trouve facilement par une recherche Google. J'ai donné en commentaire un lien qui montre que nous en sommes très loin. Je ne vois pas l'intérêt de laisser la question <strike>moisir</strike> croître pendant les années qu'il faudrait pour atteindre la qualité nécessaire. Stack Exchange est un site de questions-réponses, là c'est plutôt un simple wiki qu'il faudrait.

---

List requests are now rejected by most Stack Exchange sites. See [List questions: Community Wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki) and many other discussions on various metas. Originally list questions were accepted, but we gradually realized that the Stack Exchange format is no good for these: the outcome is inevitably a list of disconnected answers, sorted in a meaningless way, with a lot of duplication. Thus, inasmuch as this question should remain on the site, it will have a single, community wiki answer.

For the time being, the question is closed but not deleted. Therefore the answer can still be edited, all closing does is prevent new answers — which is exactly what we want if we're trying to build a list.

I'm in favor of deleting the question, because it is bad publicity for the site. For it to be good publicity, the answer would have to be an improvement on what you can already find with a simple Google search. I've given a link that shows we're very far from that. I don't see the point of leaving the question to <strike>fester</strike> grow for a few years until we reach the requisite quality. Stack Exchange is a questions and answers site, using it where a plain wiki would work best only gets us so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider myself as having enough SE experience to propose a solution regarding this question.

I know I wouldn't like to see it deleted, because it has some value, and even though it's not much at the moment, it has the potential to grow. However, I have to admit that way better answers can be found on other sites and that as such the question isn't really necessary.

As for the way it was closed and the answers aggregated, to me it seems like it's actually quite efficient that way: if a compilation is the answer we're after, than having just one community wiki answer with a big list is way easier to read. Closing the question has the added bonus that no answer can be added, yet the existing one can be edited. In my opinion, that's great, execpt for the fact people may think that it's not possible to edit the existing answer because the question is closed.

---

Et en français la même chose

Answer (score -4):

Si tu as peur de faire de la mauvaise publicité pour le site, alors regarde un peu les nombres de vues et de votes pour 4 questions du même style qui sont actuellement sur la home page de SE-Apple ! (Y a pas de trucage ;-)... Comme quoi, on dirait que les gens apprécient les listes, non ?

[image]

Comment: Apple is the exception: all other SE sites I know now reject these questions. They tend to draw a lot of visitors, and they actually work in the beginning, but later as they gather more answers they become a mess that doesn't help anybody.